# How to get range of blue dotted underlined(after dictation) string from uitextview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, autosuggest, dictation

Is there any way to find the range of blue dotted underlined string(suggestion to get the alternative text) in ios

Comment: Not getting your point. Can you explain further? A screenshot or a little more description of the problem?

Comment: Hi @Adeel Please find the updated [LInk](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9YZfopxzOv5UnVBdkF2MTgxOTg)